# write-only websocket communication (from HTTP server to browser)

Tags: jquery, c, websocket

Within my [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor) (GPLv3 free software, alpha stage, which later would be related to [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), a domain specific language to extend the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler; it is a specialized HTTP server [meta-] programmed in C, i.e. its C code will be more and more self-generated), using [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (an HTTP server library) and [jquery.websocket](https://github.com/dchelimsky/jquery-websocket/blob/master/jquery.websocket.js), I want to use websocket only for asynchronous messages in [JSON](http://json.org/) format from my specialized Web server (the MELT monitor) to the browser (e.g. a recent FireFox).

I want to avoid having a new event channel from browser to server, so my question is: does it make sense to use websockets only for HTTP server to browser asynchronous communication (and not using the other way transmission, from browser to HTTP server)?

Could the specialized HTTP server (the MELT monitor) do a [shutdown(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) with `SHUT_RD` on the websocket to disable any potential transmission thru the websocket from browser to HTTP server, or is it contrary to websockets standards? All communication from browser to server would be synchronous HTTP (e.g. AJAX).

I am just discovering websockets....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websockets are a full-duplex channel on which both sides can send data whenever they want. This makes it ideal for scenarios where the server is sending unannounced data to the client, because with previous technologies like XmlHttpRequest the server could only send data when it was previously requested to do so.

The [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) states that a standard-compliant Websocket server MUST respond to a PING-frame with a PONG-frame. When you close the channel from client to server, the client won't be able to send pings anymore. Also, the client will send a CLOSE-frame when it wants to terminate the connection which you should also listen to.

However, the standard doesn't say that your server must reply to any other frames in any specific way after the handshake is completed, so you can just ignore any incoming frames from the client except PING and CLOSE.